# how to use UTF-8 path in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I tried to search it on to solve the problem. and i found this one 
[Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window) 
and i tired to put this code in my $profile path ps1

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object 
System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8 with BOM'
```

and it's not working well  or even follow that setting

- Run intl.cpl (which opens the regional settings in Control Panel)
- Follow the instructions in the screen shot below.

this is error when i try to use nvim

```
Could not create process with command '"C:\Users\???\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin\nvim.exe" '.
```

wondering how to fix that part: ??? 
that ??? is my username part

Comment: There is nothing special you need to do to use non-ASCII characters in paths. Remove that line from your profile, it does not do what you think it does. Once you've removed that line, show the command you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Tomalak remove that all lines?

Comment: @Tomalak after remove all lines. same error

Comment: Yes, all of them & restart PowerShell. And then explain the issue you have, not your attempted solution.

Comment: post you entire code. Not a piece of it

Comment: @Roshan now i post all error. not a piece of it.

Comment: @J.K Can you confirm that your profile.ps1 file (or whatever file the code is run from) is also using an UTF8 encoding and not ANSI ? You can use [this custom function](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/get-text-file-encoding) to determine if the file is encoded properly .  I don't remember having problems with the command line ever but I did have a couple of time problems because I was running the script from a file that was ANSI encoded. Maybe this apply to you (or not).

Comment: @SagePourpre as i checked , it's encoding with UTF-8(BOM) . i will try what u suggess.

Comment: @Tomalak I tried what u said way but still not working.